# Traversal of a tree to find a node

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, binary-tree

I am searching through a tree to find a value that is passed. Unfortunately, it does not work. I started debugging it with prints, and what is weird is it actually finds the value, but skips the return statement.

```
    /**
  * Returns the node with the passed value
  */
 private TreeNode searchNodeBeingDeleted(Comparable c, TreeNode node)
 {  
  if(node == null) 
  {
   return null;
  }

  if(c.equals((Comparable)node.getValue()))
  {
   System.out.println("Here");
   return node;
  }
  else
  {
   if(node.getLeft() != null)
   {
    System.out.println("left");
    searchNodeBeingDeleted(c, node.getLeft());
   }
   if(node.getRight() != null)
   {
    System.out.println("right");
    searchNodeBeingDeleted(c, node.getRight());
   }
  }
  return null; //i think this gives me my null pointer at bottom
 }
```

It prints out the results as follows:

```
left
left
right
right
Here
right
left
right
left
right
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at Program_14.Driver.main(Driver.java:29)
```

I dont know if this will help, but here is my tree:

```
     L
   /   \
  D     R
 / \   / \
A   F M   U
 \       / \
  B     T   V
```

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
private TreeNode searchNodeBeingDeleted(Comparable c, TreeNode node)
 {  
  if(node == null) 
  {
   return null;
  }

  if(c.equals((Comparable)node.getValue()))
  {
   System.out.println("Here");
   return node;
  }
  else
  {
   if(node.getLeft() != null)
   {
    System.out.println("left");
    TreeNode n = searchNodeBeingDeleted(c, node.getLeft());
    if (n != null) {
      return n;
    }
   }
   if(node.getRight() != null)
   {
    System.out.println("right");
    TreeNode n = searchNodeBeingDeleted(c, node.getRight());
    if (n != null) {
      return n;
    }
   }
  }
  return null; //i think this gives me my null pointer at bottom
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your tree is a [binary search tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree) and not a ["regular" binary tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree).

You should return your recursive calls and not return `null` at the end of your method.

Something like this:

```
private TreeNode searchNodeBeingDeleted(Comparable c, TreeNode node) {
    if(nodle == null) return null;
    int diff = c.compareTo((Comparable)node.getValue());
    if (diff == 0) { // yes, we found a match!
        System.out.println("Here");
        return node;
    }
    else if (diff < 0) { // traverse to the left
        System.out.println("left");
        return searchNodeBeingDeleted(c, node.getLeft());
    }
    else {  // traverse to the right
        System.out.println("right");
        return searchNodeBeingDeleted(c, node.getRight());
    }
}
```

Comment: @moron, no it does not, but the 10 nodes in the OP's example ARE sorted. Could be a coincidence of course... Also, I see no reason to keep the values being stored in the tree as `Comparable` if the tree is not a BST. Nevertheless, you have a point: I added my assumption to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think you must return the value of `searchNodeBeingDeleted(c, node.getLeft())` and `searchNodeBeingDeleted(c, node.getRight())`, not just call those methods.

Comment: actually you need to return it only if it is not null

Comment: so i return both those statements, but i still get the null pointer with the following output: left, left, right, null error
it stops at the right node, but seems to return null when it finds it...

Comment: Maybe you call the method twice, which is wrong. You should take the value in a variable like this:  `TreeNode n = searchNodeBeingDeleted(c, node.getLeft());` then you test for null: 
    `if (n != null) {return n;}`

Answer (score 1):

You are using recursion in your function. The 'here' you see is the result of a function call that has been created from the same function. So it will return a value to the 'recursing' function, at this point you aren't done yet, even though you have found the answer, you still need to keep propagating it upwards.